# How to get all product SKUs in foreach loop on checkout success page?

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, sku

I am trying to add some tracking and conversion codes which require all skus from an order to be listed in the HTML tag on the checkout success page.

So far I have been able to get the QTY, Order Amount and SKU but I need to show ALL SKUs from the order not just one so need to loop but I'm doing it wrong.

Here is what I have:

```
<?php // Get Order info
$products = array();
$lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$_order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->load($lastOrderId);

/* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Order */
foreach ($_order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $info['sku'] = trim($item->getSku());
    $info['qty'] = $item->getQtyOrdered();
    $info['price'] = $item->getPrice();

    $products[] = $info;
}

$config['productInfos'] = $products;
$config['cartTotal'] = $_order->getGrandTotal();
$config['currency'] = Mage::app()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
?>
```

One I have the order info I need to populate the following HTML TAGS

```
<div id="mc_data" style="display:none;">
    <div class="mc_event">PURCHASE</div>
    <div class="mc_order_ref"><?php echo $this->getOrderId(); ?></div>
    <div class="mc_retailer">Custom</div>
//Here is where I need to loop to get all the SKUS
<?php foreach(); ?>
   <div class="mc_sku">
        <?php echo $this->getSku(); ?>
    </div> 
<?php endforeach(); ?>
    <div class="mc_ordervalue"><?php echo $_order->getGrandTotal(); ?></div>
</div>
```

I've been searching for a few hours but haven't found a good tutorial on how to get the SKUs in a foreach so could do with some assistance if possible please...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
foreach ($config['productInfos'] as $product): ?>
<div class="mc_sku">
   <?php echo $product['sku']; ?>
</div>
<?php
endforeach;
```

Comment: @user1704524 Are you using configurable products?

Comment: @user1704524 If so, then use $_order->getAllVisibleItems() instead of $_order->getAllItems().

Comment: Yes I am using mainly configurable and some simple too...